# c# write anywhere in a file

Tags: c#, file

Is it possible to write anywhere in the content of a text file ?

I did something which is reading the content of the file and when I was reading a specific line, I would add something to the content. When I reached the end of the file, I would truncate the file and write the new content but this is taking too much time because of the thousands of lines.

Is there an other solution that would take less time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write anywhere in the content of a text file. Note that you "overwrite" the content, not "insert".

You can't add ("insert") content in the middle of a file without rewriting all the file from that point onward.

You can truncate a file using the `SetLength()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i guess i will keep my solution then.